# Update existing files in a folder and it's subfolder from another folder

Tags: batch-file, directory, xcopy

I have two folders, A and B. A contains files I want to copy over to B, provided they already exist in B.

Both have a similar structure but A has more files and directories than B has, but I cannot figure out how to keep only the path relative to the inside of each directory intact.

So if I had

```
C:\FolderA\file1.txt
C:\FolderA\file2.txt
C:\FolderA\subfolder\text1.txt
C:\FolderA\subfolder\text2.txt

C:\FolderB\file2.txt
C:\FolderB\file3.txt
C:\FolderB\subfolder\text2.txt
```

It would only copy file2.txt and subfolder\text2.txt.  A sort of "only update" command.

I've come to this, executed from FolderB:

```
FOR /R %%i IN (*) DO COPY /Y "%%~nxi" "%%i"
```

Unfortunately `%%~nxi` only gets me the file, none of the internal directory structure.

Comment: Are you trying to update only the files that exist or copy the directory structure? I can't work out what your asking :)

Comment: No your answer was the right one, now I only have to get rid of empty directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `xcopy` with the switch `/u`.

```
Copy only files that already exist in destination.
```